# What is the difference when create local branch base remote branch/local?

Tags: git

I have branch master based on origin/master
I looked on the git config and I saw that that

```
branch.master.merge = refs/heads/master
branch.master.remote = origin
```

I created another branch master2 based on origin/master and I got
    branch.master2.merge = refs/heads/master
    branch.master2.remote = origin
Now I created another branch myLocalBranch based on local branch master2
I saw just the merge property was updated

```
 branch.myLocalBranch .merge = refs/heads/master
```

is it ok ?

how does it will get the information on the remote ?

When git use the information on the merge and remote  ? does it need it on fetch and pull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're going to do `try push` from yout `myLocalBranch` git will complain about not knowing what is the remote branch on origin. Newer versions of git will also give you a command to execute in console to set the remote using default settings.

```
$ git push
fatal: The current branch myLocalBranch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin myLocalBranch
```

After you run this command and redo the push, git will actualy create `myLocalBranch` on origin (assuming you have necessary priviliges on that repo).

Comment: is it ok that the myLocalBranch .master.remote didn't create ?

Comment: Yes. This is normal. In git you can work with many remote repositories, so git is not creating the remote tracking entry by default. More information here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: How you can know which remote is relevant to the local branch ?

Comment: If it's a branch you created, it's up to you to decide.